# ERROR ITMS-4134: "Duplicate in-app purchase product_id: '010'." at Software/SoftwareMetadata

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, application-loader

My app already has a few non consumable in-app purchase without content hosting. One of them has product id 010.

I have created a new in-app purchase with content hosting, when I try to upload the content via Application Loader I get this:

```
ERROR ITMS-4134: "Duplicate in-app purchase product_id: '010'." at Software/SoftwareMetadata
```

The ContentInfo.plist of the uploading content contains:

IAPProductIdentifier: T01

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, once you've created an In-App purchase product, it seems that the ID is stored permanently, even after your remove it). You have to create a new ID